# How to set the Default Page in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

Is there any section or code which allows us to set default page in `web.config`?

For example, when people first visit my website, I want them to see `CreateThing.aspx` rather than `Default.aspx`.

**The solutions I already know:**

1. Put this line of code => `Response.Redirect("CreateThings.aspx")` in `Default.aspx` `Page_Load` event but this method is really naive.
2. We can use IIS (default page configuration,) but I wanna do the same thing over on my ASP.NET application.
3. This could be another solution for now:

   ```
   <defaultDocument>
       <files>
           <clear />
           <add value="Default.aspx" />
           <add value="Default.htm" />
           <add value="Default.asp" />
           <add value="index.htm" />
           <add value="index.html" />
           <add value="iisstart.htm" />
       </files>
   </defaultDocument>
   ```

Answer (score 244, accepted):

If using IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 you can use

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="CreateThing.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/defaultDocument/

Comment: I found I needed to add the enabled="true" attribute to the defaultDocument tag i.e.: <defaultDocument enabled="true">

Comment: @JohnFerguson Cheers for that.

Comment: This is to be put in the <configuration> tag of the Web.config file.

Comment: Will this work if the Default.aspx is in another folder? For Example: <add value="/NewSite/default.aspx"/>

Comment: This didn't work for me, but user1469363's way did.  If this isn't working for anyway give his solution a try (it is very simple/easy)

Comment: Would this work for a document not in the root directory? for example if I want my default index to be "mydomain.com/folder1/index.html"

Answer (score 23):

[Tip #84: Did you know… How to set a Start page for your Web Site in Visual Web Developer?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/06/26/tip-84-did-you-know-how-to-set-a-start-page-for-your-web-site-in-visual-web-developer.aspx)

Simply right click on the page you want to be the start page and say "set as start page".

As noted in the comment below by Adam Tuliper - MSFT, this only works for debugging, not deployment.

Comment: Hmm. Works locally, but not after I deploy to azure.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did!  Thanks!

Comment: @vivekmaharajh it wasn't the default because this is meant for testing/debugging - this technique doesn't configure your web server only your development environment.

Comment: does not help redirect when users access the directory itself.

Answer (score 10):

Map default.aspx as **HttpHandler** route and redirect to CreateThings.aspx from within the HttpHandler.

```
<add verb="GET" path="default.aspx" type="RedirectHandler"/>
```

> **Make sure Default.aspx does not exists
>   physically at your application root**.
>   If it exists physically the
>   HttpHandler will not be given any
>   chance to execute. Physical file
>   overrides HttpHandler mapping.

Moreover you can re-use this for pages other than default.aspx.

```
<add verb="GET" path="index.aspx" type="RedirectHandler"/>
```

//RedirectHandler.cs in your App_Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for RedirectHandler
/// </summary>
public class RedirectHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public RedirectHandler()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    #region IHttpHandler Members

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("CreateThings.aspx");
        context.Response.End();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: So, you say when ever a request happens to `Default.aspx`, the handler will redirect the request to `CreateThing.aspx` . It looks a generic solution. Thank you.

Comment: But would it cause HttpHandler pollution ?

Comment: After your edit, I need to say : Well it could be. I think the simple thing would be like `Application.Run(new Form()1)` :)

Comment: @Arron: You can always create a custom configuration section that will configure your `HttpHandler` for various different requests. You can also catch all *.aspx requests and see if request matches any of your configured URLs. Otherwise just pass it through.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using forms authentication you could try the code below:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name=".FORM" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="CreateThings.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/"> 
</forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: To use Form Authentication, should I use the providers MemberShip or stuff ? I mean when I simply select Authentication Mode as Form rather than Windows, this code will work charmingly right ?

Comment: I would say that this depends on the solution. If you need a more complex solution with different user profiles then you should go with MembershipProviders. But if it is a more simple setup you could just use <allow users=""/> and <deny users=""/>.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using login page in your website go to web.config file

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="index.aspx"  >
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

replace your authentication tag to above (where index.aspx will be your startup page)

and one more thing write this in your web.config file inside

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
   <defaultDocument>
    <files>
     <clear />
     <add value="index.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>

  <location path="index.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the IIS default document setting using the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="DefaultPageToBeSet.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Or using the IIS, refer the link for reference http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument

Answer (score 3):

I had done all the above solutions but it did not work.

My default page wasn't an aspx page, it was an html page.

This article solved the problem.  https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/aug/15/iis-default-documents-vs-aspnet-mvc-routes

Basically, in my \App_Start\RouteConfig.cs file, I had to add a line:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("");   // This was the line I had to add here!

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Hope this helps someone, it took me a goodly while to find the answer.

Comment: I think the added code will work only for MVC apps.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the following method:

```
system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="CreateThing.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```