# Set default directory in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config, directory

Is there a way to configure the default directory in web.config?

My Default.aspx file is not in the root folder but in /Public/Default.aspx.

I found this post : [Set Default Page in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net) but it does't work, probably because it's only to configure the default page and not the default directory...

Comment: no way to do what you ask to my knowledge. Can't you put a Default.aspx file in the root directory and from that one do a redirect to your /Public/Default.aspx ? anyway this looks to me like looking for issues, have a default in the root and call your nested one something else...

Comment: Is you web application hosted some where or it's on you pc? Because from IIS you can do this by changing the settings of virtual directory. A link to walk though of dping so http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha2y9493.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to configure this in IIS.

You have your website already setup, and all you need to do is add an "Application" within that website.

**Add Application...**
[image: Add Application]

You can also create a Virtual Directory which would give a similar result. Unfortunately you will still be navigating to http://example.com/public/

My question to you is, what is in the wwwroot directory? Is there a different website? Why not launch two websites within IIS?

[Here's more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha2y9493.aspx) C/O @waqas

Comment: short answer... this isn't going to happen with web.config.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm gonna try that. I'm not the server administrator so I will ask to my co-worker to do that manip.