# Html landing page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, authentication

I have a html landing page for my asp.net website however i cannot give it to display it always goes to the login.

What can i set in web.config to fix this?

I have tried

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="index.html" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

 <location path="index.html">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="index.html" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

All with no luck. Please help
Thanks in advance

Here is my full web.config

```
 <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ArctixDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>-->
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="" />
    <add name="ArctixDbEntities" connectionString="" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        validate="false" />    
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="index.html" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location allowOverride="true">
    <appSettings>
      <add key="SMTPServer" value="" />
      <add key="SMTPServerPort" value="25" />
      <add key="SMTPServerSSL" value="false" />
      <add key="SMTPUsername" value="" />
      <add key="SMTPPassword" value="" />
      <add key="SystemEmailAddress" value="" />
      <add key="SystemEmailAddressName" value="" />
    </appSettings>
  </location>
  <location path="Styles">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="index.html">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I am hosted with a provider which has set the default page on there side to index.html. If i remove the web.config it works

Comment: and did you try <allow users="*"> under the authorization?

Comment: There is something in the web.config that is forcing it to the login.

Comment: allow users="*". Try using * instead of ?

Comment: Have a look at this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net. Might be helpful

Comment: I dont think defaulting to a aspx page is a problem. I however need to go to index.html and i dont want to have to go through a asp page to get there.

Comment: IIS is trying to go to my index.html however it tries to force a login

Answer (score 0):

I eventually just set my login page to the landing page

Answer (score 0):

Can you structure your site as follows?

- Allow the root directory / styles / etc to permit anonymous access
- Add a 'secure' directory with its own web.config, specifying forms authentication

Anything outside 'secure' will be accessible.