# How to make home page as default page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, url-mapping

How can i set default home page in asp `web.config` file.
i have already written this code :

```
<urlMappings>
  <add url="/" mappedUrl="Home.aspx"/>
  <add url="Default.aspx" mappedUrl="Home.aspx"/>
</urlMappings>
```

and also tried this

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="Home.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

but i guess its not working. when i type `www.example.com` it says directory listing is disabled, but does not redirect to `www.example/Home.aspx`.

I dont want to enable directory listing but if someone types `www.example.com` he should be send to `www.example.com/Home.aspx`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Default Page in Asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net)

Comment: @walther - what do you mean classic asp... are you talking about pipeline mode, will this work if i make it classic asp

Comment: You tagged this question with "classic asp", so I retagged it for you. Classic asp is a completely different thing. Anyway, did you put <clear /> like suggested?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change in your webconfig for iis 7.

```
<system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument>
        <files>
          <clear />
          <add value="CreateThing.aspx" />
        </files>
      </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

Take a look for this post :[Set Default Page in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thi is not working either... may be i am missing something.. please guide me where to look.

Comment: are you add Default pages name(Home.aspx,Default.aspx...etc) in your hosting server?