# ASP.NET MVC localhost:[port] shows directoryoverview instead of /Home/Index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

After reinstallation of VS08 some settings seem to be wrong.
All ASP Projects don't refer to the Homecontroller.

[image]

Instead of this, I see the whole directoryindex of the project unless I surf especially to /Home or other controllers.

Does anybody know, whats wrong now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly configure your web.config
I think this question will cover you:
    [Set Default Page in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thanks for the quick respone, but that's not exactly what i'm looking for. There must be a setting for VS which control the default site for the project. My colleagues all got the same version and project from repository and got the Indexpage as the defaultpage like me before.