# Setting default page in iis7

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have a web application which is hosted in `iis7` in amazon ec2 instance.The directory structure is like `Website>Pages>welcome.aspx`.The physical path for the iis site has been set at website level.I have added the default page as `pages/welcome.aspx`.Now when we are accessing the website the site redirects to the default page but the url remains like `abc.com:XXXX` rather than `abc.com:XXXX/pages/welcome.aspx`.Now when someone clicks on links with href like `abcd.aspx`, a page not found exception is thrown as it is searching for the content in the root directory rather than in the pages directory.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your web.config and add:

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="pages/welcome.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net).