# HTML form submitting ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, html

Actually i am submitting HTML form with action="http://localhost:8080" to ASP.NET 1.1 framework it works fine. But now same code not working on the ASP.NET 4.0. any one know, what is the reason.

When i changed the action="http://localhost:8080/action.aspx" its works fine on ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1913058/1558311). Suppose there you will find an answer

Answer (score 1):

you may not have and index or default page for asp.net 4.0

Comment: To clarify, the default page is set in IIS, not in the application itself. Probably the old version has the default set to "action.aspx", which is not a standard default page ("index" or "default" are the normal ones).