# 404 - File or directory not found. In umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, umbraco, umbraco5

I got 404 error when i run http://www.judsonsmartliving.org/jordan.

if i use http://www.judsonsmartliving.org/jordan/index.html ,then its working.

I found some solution to resolve this but they are not working for me.

I tried some solutions in webconfig:

```
  1)<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  2)<location path="Site Description">
  <system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

But after adding these solutions in webconfig i got 505 error.

Comment: Have you set the `UseExtensionlessUrls` setting to true?

Comment: Hi Grant  where to set UseExtensionlessUrls=true

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default navigation page settings in webconfig like below

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="CreateThing.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Ref : [Set Default Page in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net)