# ASP.NET not loading defaultUrl

Tags: asp.net, web-config

If have the following code in my Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/Default.aspx" defaultUrl="/Webpages/Main.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

however when I run the application a different web page is being loaded first

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Default Page in Asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net)

Comment: Are you running this through Visual Studio or a browser?

Comment: The reason I ask is I have noticed that in VS2012 if you have an `.aspx` page open in the editor and run (F5), then it will launch that page in the browser instead of any set default/start page.

Comment: It runs the one you're viewing just if you didn't set the default page for the website/project.

Comment: I am using VS2010 and I also tried adding the default document in the web.config

Answer (score 0):

Add `Default Document` under the `<system.webServer>` tag in  `Web.config`

```
<defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear/>
            <add value="login.aspx"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Please clarify if you are running it from Visual Studio or accessing application hosted in IIS

Comment: Exactly please specify, If you running application over hosted on IIS then it will definitely work.