# Upload ASP.NET web site with file upload

Tags: asp.net, upload

I made an ASP.NET web site using visual studio 2012. I registered a free domain and now I need to upload the project using for example FileZilla. Can you tell me which files exctly should I upload and do I need to set a starting page in my project or I need a Default.aspx page in it. I also have an MSSQL database. Any suggestions how to upload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can publish your code using this - right click on project , select publish, choose filesystem , and then save published code to target file system and then copy that directory to required domain using FileZilla. Also you can directly copy solution project , but it is recommended to host published code.

You can set startup page using `web.config` - [Set Default Page in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net)

Regarding DB thing - you need to make sure, required domain has MSSQL, if that has, then copy required DB and attach to DB server, extract connection string ( DB server address, DB name , credential) and update that in web.config of hosted website.

Comment: Visual Studio can actually FTP directly, without Filezilla. It even supports secure connections.