# is there a way to reroute from folder to page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net (web forms) website where I have different pages in supplier & customer folders.
ex. localhost/supplier/index.aspx &
localhost/customer/index.aspx .
If someone tries to open "localhost/supplier" he would get error.Is there a way to route the links to their respective index pages?

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set in the web config the default document

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">    <!-- this line enables default documents for a directory -->
   <files>      
       <clear/>     <!-- removes the existing default document list -->                
       <add value="foo.htm"/>     <!-- foo.htm is now the default document  -->                
       <add value="foo.php"/>     <!-- 2nd default document in search order -->                
       <add value="foo.aspx/>     <!-- 3rd default document in search order -->                
       <add value="foo.cfm/>      <!-- 4th default document in search order -->
   </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

> The default document is returned to the client when the browser
> requests a directory name (foo.com/, foo.com/somedir/), but doesn't
> specify a page.
>
> - [http://www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-default-website-document.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119160405/http://www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-default-website-document.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[disable directory browsing in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx)